# How to Add a Javadoc Directory to a Wordpress Site

Tags: java, wordpress, javadoc

I am hosting a Wordpress site and would like to use it to publish an open source project. I'd like one of the main menu items to link to the javadoc for the project.  For those, unfamiliar with Java, javadoc is a programmatically generated directory hierarchy with many (too many to convert manually) HTML files. The root level contains the index.html file that you start with and all the references are relative to that directory. How can I hook in this structure to the WP site?  Converting each page by hand to a WP page is not an acceptable solution because there are too many of them and they change regularly.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

Within my WordPress folder I created a folder *javadoc* - right next to *wp-admin* and the like - and dumped all the created JavaDoc-html in there. Going to *http://my-blog/javadoc* nicely displays the docs.

I'm a novice in this area, so this might be inadvisable from a best practice or security point of view. I'm actually very interested in an opinion on that!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could create a directory in the WordPress root giving read-only permissions and place the files generated by javadoc there and then point a link to it, this is definitely the easiest way. The javadoc files are plain html, in my opinion there is not much to do in terms of security, there are no cookies, database access, but only a javascript to find in the pages. Another aspect is the SEO plugins that with this method will not insert the javadoc pages in the sitemap.xml and will have to be inserted manually.

You could insert an iframe in a post so that the javadoc is integrated into the page, but the problem with SEO plugins remains.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).